# Joomla Purity III template footer blocks align on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, joomla, responsive-design, joomla3.0

I created site with Joomla CMS and using Purity III template - http://magadanfitness.ru/. All works fine, customer happy, but i still have one issue.

On normal screens all works just fine, but if you open it on mobile device, footer blocks did not align normal, and looks like this:

[image]

I try different ways to fix that, but without success.

Here my footer layout:

[image]

How to fix this, so all buttons arranges like that???

```
BTN     BTN

BTN     BTN
    BTN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the following css attribute:
`min-height: 110px;`

this will give the items a minimum height of 110px so that they don't take the space of the next icons area.